# asp.net webpage defaultDocument button click not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have developed an asp.net website in VS2010. The defaultDocument is set to default.aspx in the root directory, as I have dome many times before.

For reasons unknown an asp:button in default.aspx is not firing correctly when the url is typed in without the file extension.

For example, if I type the url www.mywebsite.com the default.aspx page will load as expected, however, the button will not fire (it does postback but doesn't fire the server click event).

If i type in the url www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx it works as expected.

The problem I'm having only occurs in a live environment (I cannot recreate the error on the localhost).

Any idea's?

Comment: Are other asp.net websites running on the live server? Do they work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Sorted this out last night. It turned out it was an HttpModule of the Telerik web controls I use, in the web.config.

RadCompression... (or something similar). It compresses and cleans up code after an ajax response.

I have no idea why it was affecting the defaultDocument only, but removing it solved my problem.